# How to combine variable with string value

Tags: c++

I want to combine variable with string value in (ofstream) file path

**Example:**

```
long phNumber;
char bufPhNumber[20];
ofstream ifile;

cout << "Phone Number: ";
cin >> phNumber;
itoa(phNumber,bufPhNumber,20);

ifile.open("c://" + bufPhNumber + ".txt",ios::out);  // error in this line
```

How to combine  this variable (bufPhNumber) with that strings ( "c://" +  variable here + ".txt" )

Answer (score 4):

Do this:

```
ifile.open((std::string("c://") + bufPhNumber + ".txt").c_str(),ios::out);
```

**Explanation :**

It first creates a string, and concatenates the rest of  c-strings using `operator+()` as:

```
std::string temp = std::string("c://") + bufPhNumber + ".txt";
```

then takes `c_str()` and pass this to `.open()`:

```
ifile.open(temp.c_str(),ios::out);
```

However, in C++11, you don't need to do `.c_str()`, and you can use `std::string` directly.

---

A better solution should be this:

```
std::string phNumber; //declare it as std::string

cout << "Phone Number: ";
cin >> phNumber; //read as string

         //use constructor
ofstream ifile(("c://" + phNumber + ".txt").c_str(), ios::out);
```

Comment: Your better solution has a typo in the `ofstream` ctor. It's still `bufPHNumber`.

Comment: @Nawaz: thanks for your answer but this is not that I want, i want to use int value and convert to char and then use it in file path, I don't want to use string type instead int type or long

Comment: @LionKing Using an integer type for a phone number is a bad idea anyway. What about leading `0`s or `+`s or ` ` seperators or `-` separators. A phone number is really just an identifier, it's for human convenience that the symbols are decimal numbers and not from some other strange alphabet.

Answer (score 1):

`ofstream::open`, at least before C++11 <sup>(a)</sup>, requires a `const char *` for the file name, not a `std::string`, as per [here](http://new.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ofstream/open/).

Instead of:

```
ifile.open("c://" + bufPhNumber + ".txt",ios::out);
```

use the following:

```
string fspec = std::string ("c://") + bufPhNumber + ".txt";
ifile.open (fspec.c_str(), ios::out);
```

(and you may want to consider why your *output* file is called `ifile`).

---

<sup>(a)</sup> In C++11, there are *two* `open` functions for `basic_ofstream`:

```
void open(const char* s, ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::out);
void open(const string& s, ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::out);
```

so a `string` version would work there.

Comment: @rubenvb: good point. I updated the answer to cover that. Thanks.

Comment: paxdiablo: a new Standard that provides so many useful conveniences should not go unadvertised :)

Answer (score -1):

Okay, hi. You can't concatenate strings directly like in java, so your issue is here:

> bufPhNumber + ".txt"

Given bufPhNumber is a char * and text is a char *, they don't support the + operator in the way that you intend.

There is strcat() for such a job, but it assumes the target string has enough room for the destination string, and it also modifies the target string.

```
char Array[28]; //One for the null
strcat(Array,"C:\\");
strcat(Array,bufPhNumber);
strcat(Array,".txt");
```

Although I recommend using a char array for phone numbers as long isn't very well suited for such storage as it can't hold as many digits as you like (you might consider using two ints/longs). Also, consider using unsigned long (as you don't get negative phone numbers). If you do use long/int, note that conversion from long to char array, and char array to long will take a chunk of memory and processing power, which on a bigger scale is less efficient than just using char arrays.

Comment: Wrong answer. This is a question about C++ and not C and you can perfectly concatenate `std::string`s "like in Java". You just cannot do it with plain `char` pointers.

Comment: @ChristianRau: I have the correct answer, as by strings I refer to char strings (note plural) and not std::string (which I always denote with std:: to distinguish). Note the phrase `Given bufPhNumber is a char * and text is a char *, they don't support the + operator`. **There are no std::strings involved in his code**. Please denote in context (Java operates with char arrays as though strings, C++ does not).

Comment: The answer may only be regarded as correct in that it works in C++, but it's definitely a C answer (or maybe a C/C++ answer, which doesn't make it better). In C++ char arrays are used as char arrays, but definitely not as strings, whatever strange dialect the OP might use. Your answer just went into the wrong direction, explaining to him how to concatenate char arrays, istead of how to convert his char array into a string.

Comment: And by the way, I doubt that you can use Java's string functions on a `byte[]` array, though I have to admit I don't have much Java experience. Isn't `String` a class, too?